# Vue not rendering UI changes when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is probably a dumb question, but whenever I submit a form to post a new product to the `productsList` the UI does not render it immediately, only after I reload the page. I'm posting the data and fetching it from firebase

ProductList.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="product-list">
    <NewItemForm></NewItemForm>
    <ul>
      <ProductListItem
        v-for="product in productsList"
        v-bind:key="product.product.id"
        :title="product.product.title"
        :price="+product.product.price"
        :id="product.product.id"
      />
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProductListItem from "./ProductListItem.vue";
import NewItemForm from "./NewItemForm.vue";
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "ProductList",
  components: {
    ProductListItem,
    NewItemForm,
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getProducts"]),
  },

  computed: { ...mapGetters(["productsList"]) },

  created() {
    this.getProducts();
  },
};
</script>
```

store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    products: [],
  },

  mutations: {
    addNewProduct: (state, product) => {
      product.id = product.name;
      state.products.unshift(product);
    },
    setProducts: (state, products) => {
      for (const name in products) {
        products[name].product.id = name;
        state.products = [...state.products, products[name]];
      }
    },
  },

  getters: {
    productsList: (state) => state.products,
  },

  actions: {
    async addNewProduct({ commit }, product) {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://vue-s-261e8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json",
        product
      );
      commit("addNewProduct", response.data);
    },

    async getProducts({ commit }) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "https://vue-s-261e8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json"
        );
        commit("setProducts", response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
  },
});
```

NewItemForm.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form class="form">
      <label for="name">Product name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" v-model="product.title" />
      <label for="description">Product description</label>
      <input type="text" name="description" v-model="product.description" />
      <label for="price">Product price</label>
      <input type="text" name="price" v-model="product.price" />
    </form>
    <button class="button" type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="onSubmit">
      Add new item
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "NewItemForm",

  data() {
    return {
      product: {
        title: "",
        description: "",
        price: "",
      },
    };
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addNewProduct"]),
    onSubmit() {
      this.addNewProduct({
        product: this.product,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I have tried to setup a watcher, but that only introduced an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue 2 has some quirky behaviour with state, specifically when dealing with arrays. I believe in this case you'd need to use `Vue.set`, which you can find more details about from the below link, there you can also find more documentation about reactivity in Vue 2.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

You also appear to be missing a component from your example (ProductListItem.vue)

I'd recommend upgrading to Vue 3 and take advantage of [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/), as that is now the replacement for VueX.

If you could upload a repository with the problem in full, I'd happily take a look.

Edit:

After reviewing the repository, this looks like the fix:

change the `addNewProduct` mutation to the following:

```js
addNewProduct: (state, product) => {
    product.id = product.name;
    // this particular change might not be required
    // feel free to try without
    state.products = [...state.products, product]
},
```

and finally change the `addNewProduct` action to the following:

```js
async addNewProduct({ commit }, product) {
    await axios.post(
      "https://vue-s-261e8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json",
       product
    );
    commit("addNewProduct", product);
}
```

This should fix your reactivity issues and correctly update your array. Hope this helped :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried to use `Vue.set`, but it did not seem to work or I have not used it correctly. I'll leave the github repo here: https://github.com/JuozasPetryla/vue-learn.git . And as for using Vue 3 and Pinia -  I would do that, but the internship I have enrolled at specificaly asked me to study the older version of Vue with Vuex.

Comment: I have updated my comment, this should help address your issues :) @JuozasPetryla

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution to my problem :)